# XML Path Loop Inline

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

I am utilizing a sparsely populated version of the TCP-H database attempting to output data about orders using XML path. I have a query to find for each supplier and the part they supply, aggregated numbers about all the orders and wish to include a list of every orders info under a single orders element. I can do this in Oracle with just a single query so it looks like

```html
<orderedPart>
  <partName partKey="100">Part#100</partName>
  <supplierName supplierKey="1">Supplier#1</supplierName>
  <totalQty>32</totalQty>
  <orderCount>2</orderCount>
  <orders>
    <order orderKey="4928">
      <orderDate>1993-10-04</orderDate>
      <orderQty>4</orderQty>
    </order>
    <order orderKey="1223">
      <orderDate>1996-05-25</orderDate>
      <orderQty>28</orderQty>
    </order>
  </orders>
</orderedPart>
```

However, in my current SQL Server 2008 my query is current outputting them separately like

```html
<orderedPart>
  <partName partKey="100">Part#100</partName>
  <supplierName supplierKey="1">Supplier#1</supplierName>
  <totalQty>32</totalQty>
  <orderCount>2</orderCount>
  <orders>
    <order orderKey="4928">
      <orderDate>1993-10-04</orderDate>
      <orderQty>4</orderQty>
    </order>
  </orders>
</orderedPart>
<orderedPart>
  <partName partKey="100">Part#100</partName>
  <supplierName supplierKey="1">Supplier#1</supplierName>
  <totalQty>32</totalQty>
  <orderCount>2</orderCount>
  <orders>
    <order orderKey="1223">
      <orderDate>1996-05-25</orderDate>
      <orderQty>28</orderQty>
    </order>
  </orders>
</orderedPart>
```

In Oracle using the XMLAGG this works fine but I have not been able to find an equivalent in SQL Server 2008 in my searching. I want to do this within the SQL query ideally like I can in Oracle without having to process it after with scripts. The query currently is

```css
select l.l_partKey as 'partName/@partKey', p.p_name as partName, l.l_suppKey as 'supplierName/@supplierKey', s.s_name as supplierName,
(select sum(d.l_quantity)
 from lineitem d
 where d.l_partkey = p.p_partKey and d.l_suppKey = s.s_suppKey
 group by l_partKey) as totalQty,
(select count(d.l_orderKey)
 from lineitem d
 where d.l_partKey = l.l_partKey and d.l_suppKey = l.l_suppKey
 group by d.l_partKey) as orderCount,

(select l.l_orderKey as '@orderKey', o.o_orderDate as orderDate, l.l_quantity as orderQty 
 where l.l_partKey = p.p_partkey and l.l_suppkey = s.s_suppkey and l.l_orderKey = o.o_orderKey
 order by o.o_orderDate desc
 for xml path('order'), root('orders'), type)
 
from lineitem l, supplier s, part p, orders o
where l.l_partKey = p.p_partkey and l.l_suppkey = s.s_suppkey and l.l_orderKey = o.o_orderKey
order by p.p_name asc
for xml path('orderedPart'), root('orderedParts'), type;
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider two approaches that work well together:

1. An [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) script since you essentially require an XML transformation. Much like SQL (a special-purpose declarative programming language), XSLT is also a special-purpose declarative language used to style, transform, format XML files in various end-use structures.
2. A general purpose language like Java, C#, PHP, Python, VB to call the XSLT; this is a database agnostic solution and not restricted to any RDMS (Oracle, SQL Server, Postgre, MySQL, etc.); also, general purpose languages can connect to any RDMS using ODBC/OLEDB drivers to import needed data. See below example scripts.

As mentioned, the two above approaches work great together as nearly every general-purpose language maintains an XSLT processor. Specifically for your needs, you need to group orders by the partName node. In XSLT 1.0, you can use the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

**XSLT** script (to be saved externally as .xsl file)

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="orderid" match="orderedPart" use="partName" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
   <orderedPart>
    <xsl:for-each select="orderedPart[count(. | key('orderid', partName)[1]) = 1]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="partName"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="supplierName"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="totalQty"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="orderCount"/>

      <xsl:for-each select="key('orderid', partName)">      
        <xsl:copy-of select="orders"/>       
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </orderedPart>
  </xsl:template>   

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python** script to transform (using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) module)

```
import os
import lxml.etree as ET

cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))    

dom = ET.parse(os.path.join(cd, 'Original.xml'))
xslt = ET.parse(os.path.join(cd, 'Transform.xsl'))

transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True,  xml_declaration=True)

xmlfile = open(os.path.join(cd, 'Final.xml'),'wb')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

**PHP** script to transform (using [XSL](http://php.net/manual/en/xsl.examples.php) extension)

```
$cd = dirname(__FILE__);

$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->load($cd.'/Original.xml');

$xslfile = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xslfile->load($cd.'/Transform.xsl');

// Tranform XML with XSLT
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xslfile); 
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// Save output to file
$finalxml = $cd.'/Final.xml';
file_put_contents($finalxml, $newXml);
```

**VBA** script to transform (use in MS Excel macro or MS Access module using [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object)

```
Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument 
Dim xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument

xmlDoc.Load ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Original.xml"    
xslDoc.Load ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Transform.xsl"

xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
newDoc.Save ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Final.xml"
```

**R** script to transform (unfortunately to date, R does not have a dedicated CRAN XSLT library for PC users but R can use the MSXML object via [RDCOMClient](http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMClient/) package, but see fellow SO user [hrbrmstr's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457051/hrbrmstr) [Git](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/xslt) project)

```
library(RDCOMClient)
setwd("C:\\Path\\To\\Working\\Directory")

xmlfile = COMCreate("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xslfile = COMCreate("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
newxmlfile = COMCreate("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

xmlfile.async = FALSE
xmlfile$Load("Original.xml")

xslfile.async = FALSE
xslfile$Load("Transform.xsl")

xmlfile$transformNodeToObject(xslfile, newxmlfile)
newxmlfile$Save("Final.xml")
```

**SAS** script to transform (using [proc xsl](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003356141.htm) which uses the open-source Xalan-Java XSLT processor)

```
proc xsl 
    in="C:\Path\To\Original.xml"
    xsl="C:\Path\To\Transform.xsl"
    out="C:\Path\To\Final.xml";
run;
```

Still other examples in Java, C#, Perl, etc. Above examples are for future readers' references.

**Eventual Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<orderedPart>
  <partName partKey="100">Part#100</partName>
  <supplierName supplierKey="1">Supplier#1</supplierName>
  <totalQty>32</totalQty>
  <orderCount>2</orderCount>
  <orders>
    <order orderKey="4928">
      <orderDate>1993-10-04</orderDate>
      <orderQty>4</orderQty>
    </order>
  </orders>
  <orders>
    <order orderKey="1223">
      <orderDate>1996-05-25</orderDate>
      <orderQty>28</orderQty>
    </order>
  </orders>
</orderedPart>
```

Comment: +1 A great all around set of answers, it just seems odd that I wouldn't within the query somehow like Oracles XMLAGG. With queries where I have a single entry in an outer tag I can select distinct on the outermost value and get it to group nicely but that becomes difficult with the multiple outer elements here. I am adjusting the wording of the question to make it clearer I am really trying to keep it to the query like the Oracle version rather than process with scripts after.

Comment: Thanks, this is mostly for future readers. While there may be a way in Oracle, we hate for you to ask yet another question when time to move to MySQL or Postgre or DB2 or other. I just provide an alternative to use XSLT that can natively transform XML instead of SQL, a limited language type best used for [DDL and DML](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_are_the_difference_between_ddl_dml_and_dcl_commands) procedures.

Comment: Yes, it just seems like if Oracle has a function to that affect the others would have it or a trick to and I have just overlooked it

Comment: Your answer is great, worth an upvote. But this is easy to get directly with a `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH()` query. Posted an answer...

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a while ago, but SQL Server offers full control over the output with `FOR XML PATH`. This is the way one would do it:

Remark: I added one more part and one more order to demonstrate the deeper nesting:

```
DECLARE @suppl TABLE(supplKey INT,supplName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @suppl VALUES (1,'supplier#1');

DECLARE @part TABLE(partKey INT, partName VARCHAR(100),supplID INT);
INSERT INTO @part VALUES (100,'part#100',1)
                        ,(200,'part#200',1);

DECLARE @order TABLE(orderKey INT, orderDate DATE, orderQty INT,partID INT);
INSERT INTO @order VALUES (4928,{d'1993-10-04'},4,100)
                         ,(1223,{d'1995-05-25'},28,100)
                         ,(1111,{d'1998-05-25'},10,200);

WITH OrderedParts AS
(
    SELECT partID,partName
          ,supplKey,supplName
          ,COUNT(*) AS orderCount
          ,SUM(orderQty) AS totalQty
    FROM @order AS o
    INNER JOIN @part AS p ON o.partID=p.partKey
    INNER JOIN @suppl AS s ON p.supplID=s.supplKey
    GROUP BY partID,partName,supplKey,supplName
)
SELECT partID AS [partName/@partKey]
      ,partName
      ,supplKey AS [supplierName/@supplierKey]
      ,supplName AS supplierName
      ,totalQty
      ,orderCount
      ,(
        SELECT orderKey AS [@orderKey]
              ,orderDate         
              ,orderQty         
        FROM @order AS innerO
        WHERE innerO.partID=OrderedParts.partID
        FOR XML PATH('order'),ROOT('orders'),TYPE
       ) 
FROM OrderedParts
FOR XML PATH('OrderedPart'),ROOT('OrderedParts')
```

The result

```
<OrderedParts>
  <OrderedPart>
    <partName partKey="100">part#100</partName>
    <supplierName supplierKey="1">supplier#1</supplierName>
    <totalQty>32</totalQty>
    <orderCount>2</orderCount>
    <orders>
      <order orderKey="4928">
        <orderDate>1993-10-04</orderDate>
        <orderQty>4</orderQty>
      </order>
      <order orderKey="1223">
        <orderDate>1995-05-25</orderDate>
        <orderQty>28</orderQty>
      </order>
    </orders>
  </OrderedPart>
  <OrderedPart>
    <partName partKey="200">part#200</partName>
    <supplierName supplierKey="1">supplier#1</supplierName>
    <totalQty>10</totalQty>
    <orderCount>1</orderCount>
    <orders>
      <order orderKey="1111">
        <orderDate>1998-05-25</orderDate>
        <orderQty>10</orderQty>
      </order>
    </orders>
  </OrderedPart>
</OrderedParts>
```